# Envelope does not contain document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

After creating envelope and adding document (pdf) to it, Then I receive the email, and sign the document,
when I later retrieve the envelope there is no document in it.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = "Please sign the document",
    Documents = new List<Document>(documents),
    Recipients = recipients,
    Status = "sent"
};

// 2. Use the SDK to create and send the envelope
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
EnvelopeSummary results = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
```

Later retrieve the envelope by ID

```
var envelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, results.Envelopes.FirstOrDefault().EnvelopeId);
```

Then EnvelopeDocuments is null.

How do I get the signed document?

Comment: are you sure you have the same envelopeId? check your results object, it contains the envelopeId, ensure you use it in the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to use this method:

```
envelopesApi.GetDocument (accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
```

documentId is what you set it, could be "1" if you followed common examples.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the special documentId `"combined"` to return all of the envelope's documents.

See the [EnvelopeDocuments:get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get) docs.